# initWithContentsOfFile:path] memory management when returns nil

Tags: iphone, uiimage, release, alloc

`[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]`

return nil when the method can't initialize the image. Then next code is not releasing the allocated UIImage, as image is nil in the `[image release]` line:

```
UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
if(image)
{
....
}
//Here image is nil and not releases allocated UIImage.
[image release];
```

Is this really a memory leak?

if init returns nil, how must release the object?
if I do 
UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

and image is nil because init fails, 
[image release] is the same as [nil release]. Ok there's not an error, but is not releasing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Retain count in this example has nothing to do with whether or not the image is nil. You manually allocated the image using

```
UIImage* test = [UIImage alloc];
```

and therefore the retain count will be one until you manually release it, as you are the sole owner of that object.

See [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) for more information on the subject.

Comment: yes but if init returns nil, how must release the object?
if I do 
UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

and image is nil, 
[image release] is the same as [nil release], and is not releasing the allocated object

Comment: You don't need to release it as it is nil, although it doesn't hurt to call `[image release]` anyway as the image may not always be nil. Please don't use retain count to determine if an object is taking up memory as the two very different things; this is where I think you are getting confused. Please see the link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

`release` on `nil` is a no-op, so always ok. And it won't leak as you didn't have an object to start with.

```
UIImage* test = [UIImage alloc];
```

`test` is already an `UIImage` object on its own (though you failed to initialize it at this line).

You really should *always* do alloc/init on the same line (and on the same variable) - or the code logic is really hard to follow. Your code generates only one object, and then assigns it to another variable.

This is the same, though much clearer:

```
UIImage* test = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
UIImage* image = test;
int n = [test retainCount]
```

Here it is obvious that `test` and `image` are the same object (and hence have the same `retainCount`). Whenever you release one of them, the the object goes away (unless you `retain` it before).

Please also note that `retainCount` is *not* something you should rely on or make much assumptions on. It often is misleading at best.

Comment: If alloc/init returns nil, there is no memory left that you need to release. Everything is fine. And calling release on nil won't hurt, which is convenient.